# Showing that $\phi_1 + \phi_2 - \phi$ is a boundary

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

We defined the standard $n$-simplex with ordering as $$ \sigma_n = \left\{ (t_0, \ldots, t_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : \sum_i t_i = 1, t_i \geq 0 \right\}. $$ Then $S_n(X) $ is defined as the free abelian group whose basis is the set of all singular $n$-simplices of $X$. There is a boundary operator $\partial: S_n(X) \rightarrow S_{n-1} (X)$ given by $$ \partial = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^{i} \partial_i. $$

**Problem:** Consider a singular $1$-simplex $\phi: \sigma_1 \rightarrow X: (t_0, t_1) \mapsto \phi(t_0, t_1). $ Choose any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 < a < 1$ and define two other singular $1$-simplices as $$ \phi_1: \sigma_1 \rightarrow X: (t_0, t_1) \rightarrow \phi(t_0 + t_1 (1-a) , t_1 a) $$ and $$ \phi_2 : \sigma_1 \rightarrow X: (t_0 , t_1) \mapsto \phi(t_0 (1-a), t_0 a + t_1). $$ I have to prove that $\phi_1 + \phi_2 - \phi$ is a boundary.

I'm not sure how to prove this. I already proved that a constant path is a boundary, and also that $\psi + \psi^{-1}$ (where $\psi^{-1}$ is the path traversed in opposite direction)) is a boundary. I think I may need to use this here, but not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you the intuition behind the answer and someone else can fill in the exact details but here is the gist of it. Say you have some $1$-simplex $\phi$ in your space $X$:

[image]

You should picture $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ as the two $1$-simplices which join together to form $\phi$ like this:

[image]

Then if we can find a $2$-simplex $\sigma: \Delta^2 \rightarrow X$ such that $\partial_1 \sigma = \phi$, $\partial_0 \sigma = \phi_1$, $\partial_2 \sigma = \phi_2$ then it's easy to check that $\partial \sigma = \phi_1 + \phi_2 - \phi$. We construct $\sigma$ as the composition of these functions:

[image]
The first map $f:\Delta^2 \rightarrow \Delta^1$ projects the top point of the triange to the point in $\Delta^1$ such that the red bit in $\Delta^1$ is of length $a$ thus "squishing" $\Delta^2$ leaving the bottom portion fixed and the second map is just $\phi : \Delta^1 \rightarrow X$.

You can intuitively see that $\sigma$ fits our criteria. Restricting $\sigma$ to the appropriate boundaries gives the maps we wanted and I have coloured in the appropriate colours to make this easier to see.

I'm pretty sure that $f$ is given by $(t_0, t_1, t_2) \mapsto (1-t_0 - (1-a)t_1,t_0 + (1-a)t_1)$ but can not verify it for myself so not 100% certain

Comment: Does the bottom part of the triangle gets mapped to the initial point of the line segment, by $f$?

Comment: No, f is a projection from the solid triangle onto its bottom part. I.e the bottom part stays fixed and the red gets mapped on to the red area and the blue gets mapped onto the blue area